# Fill nan-s with percentage of last valid value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns containing NaN values. I'd like to fill these with values. Fillna() with method "ffill" is nearly something I would like to have, but not exactly. I would like to have the 120% of the last valid value replacing my NaNs. So if the last valid value before a NaN is 100.0, then I would like to have 120.0 at the position of NaN.

I know I can iterate my df over, but that would require a lot of time. (my df has around 100.000 rows right now and will increase further)

Example:
df is my initial dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0], [3, 4, np.nan, 1], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5], [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4], [5, 4, 2, np.nan], [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]], columns=list('ABCD'))`

```
>>> df
    A    B    C    D
0  NaN  2.0  NaN  0.0
1  3.0  4.0  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
3  NaN  3.0  NaN  4.0
4  5.0  4.0  2.0  NaN
5  NaN  3.0  NaN  4.0
```

And this is what I would like to get:

```
>>> df
    A    B    C    D
0  NaN  2.0  NaN  0.0
1  3.0  4.0  NaN  1.0
2  3.6  NaN  NaN  5.0
3  3.6  3.0  NaN  4.0
4  5.0  4.0  2.0  NaN
5  6.0  3.0  NaN  4.0
```

So column "A" had two replacements in line num. 2 and 3, both has a value of 3.6 now (3*1.2) instead of the NaN, plus a change in line num 5, where Nan gets replaced to 6 (5*1.2)
I do not care about NaNs at the beginning, they can stay. And I would like to do the change only in column "A".

Comment: You should provide an "input" and "desired output", I dont know if all valid values are before the nan, are if they are shuffled. What happens if the first value is a nan?

Comment: Thanks your feedback BlueSheepToken, issue updated according to your request.

Comment: thank you very much, it is a lot clearer ! I will try to have a look at it. (unfortunately, I am not that good in pandas, I will try to look for the equivalent of window functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a partial column, to check if it was a NaN value before the `ffill`

As follow :

```
df['partially_filled_A'] = df['A'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['isNan'] = df['A'].isnull()

df['A_filled'] = np.where((df['isNan']) & (df['partially_filled_A'].isnull() == False), df['partially_filled_A']*1.2, df['A'])

df
```

I made a little comparison with `iteritems`, and here are the results:

```
df = pd.concat([df for _ in range(500_000)]) # let's make a df with 3_000_000 rows for the benchmark
```

#### using iteritems

```
%% time
l = []
last_value = None
for item, frame in df['A'].iteritems():
    if last_value is None:
        if pd.notnull(frame):
            last_value = frame * 1.2
            l.append(frame)
        else:
            l.append(np.nan)
    else:
        if pd.notnull(frame):
            l.append(frame)
            last_value = frame * 1.2
        else:
            l.append(last_value)
df['ans'] = l
# 2.5 seconds
```

#### using `np.where`

```
%%time
df['partially_filled_A'] = df['A'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['isNan'] = df['A'].isnull()

df['A_filled'] = np.where((df['isNan']) & (df['partially_filled_A'].isnull() == False), df['partially_filled_A']*1.2, df['A'])
#100 ms
```

As seen in this quick benchmark, I strongly suggest you to use a `np.where`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works as I expected! I tried only the np.where method, since it was faster according to you benchmark, and it is shorter, nicer code. Did exactly what I wanted.